# System settings stopped showing up

Tags: 14.04, unity, settings, system-settings, dialog

After I have placed my hard drive with Ubuntu 14.04.1 in a new pc system settings won't show up. I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

but I get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what can I do?

**EDIT**

The issue may be connected with mesa packages that I had from [xorg edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and I have noticed that

- `unity-control-center` depends on `libcheese7`
- `libcheese7` depends on `gstreamer1.0-clutter`
- `gstreamer1.0-clutter` depends on `libcogl15`
- `libcogl15 depends` on `libegl1-mesa-drivers`
- `libegl1-mesa-drivers` depends on `libegl1-mesa-drivers`
- `libegl1-mesa-drivers` depends on `libglapi-mesa ( = 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 )`

and I have installed :

`libglapi-mesa 10.5.0~git20150105.21a280f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty` from xorg-edgers PPA.

I have tried installing it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa=10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
 libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed
 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libclutter-1.0-0 (>= 1.13.10) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
 libcogl-pango15 : Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have that PPA already disabled with

```
sudo ppa-purge  ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Run`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and logout/reboot the computer.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies http://paste.ubuntu.com/9885387/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem has been with the dependencies, namely

`libegl1-mesa-drivers` depending on `libglapi-mesa ( = 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 )` (maybe should be `>=`)

I have added the xorg-edgers PPA again and then properly downgraded with ppa-purge as so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo ppa-purge  ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update
```

and now I have all packages from xorg-edgers removed and system settings dialog opens up :)

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved it

Comment: Hello from 2019 where some of us are still running 14.04 (LTS baby). This solved my issue as well.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug report for this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1428972). (The solution came from the #10 reply)

And apparently my issue was solved by entering the following line:

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev libcheese7 libcheese-gtk23 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcogl15 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-0
```

Comment: Thank you! It solves my problem with "libcheese-gtk23" and "libcheese7"

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `sudo apt-get install -f unity-control-center` or search for the missing package names and install them manually.

Comment: I get the same error message with your command :/

Comment: This is the very first solution found in many places on the web, and so was not a useful response. (does not work displays silly libcheese errors)