# New pc, decent specifications and it doesn't work up to par. What's wrong?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games

**Problem:**

Freshly built pc that I'm fairly certain can run the Portal series. The problem is that is doesn't and won't even play simple 2d-games. Examples of games I tried King Arthur's gold, project zomboid and tf2 after portal 2 didnt work. The main thing noticeable in 2d games is a screech periodically from the speakers (kag), input lag from the keyboard and mouse and general low fps (15-30) playing but loading is normal. 3d games are unplayable in game- maybe 5-10 frames tops on low- but the menus work and loading is short enough. There's also a weird pixelated green splash across the screen for both dimensions (especially tf2) . Hopefully that explains the issues occuring.

**My Specs:**

intel i7-4790

Asus gtx750ti

1 8-GB g-skill 1600 MHz Ram

1TB Harddrive

**Questions and install info:**

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu (14.04) using unetbootin from a sd card ported through an usb socket converter that changes sd to usb. Is this the issue? Do I need the nvidia drivers? Is it the single ram?

**Reason of asking:**

Most solutions I find with similar context have terminal involved solutions and I'm not comfortable enough to use terminal and guess that their problem is mine as well (I dont want to guess on terminal really). The next course of action was to re-install and if that fails get a oem for windows 10 or 7.

Comment: Are you using the proprietary nvidia driver or the open source one?

Comment: Open source i'm fairly certain nouveau instead of  the nvidia driver

Comment: Have you tried switching to the proprietary one? You can do that in system setting, in software sources on the 'Additional Drivers' tab.

Comment: Another error that lead me to a different fix 

[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/671498/ubuntu-steam-doesnt-launch)
 
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1447125378)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

Comment: How much Dedicated RAM does Steam have?

Comment: Yet to change it, so the default steam would have.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installed ubuntu and everything was fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/492216)

Comment: @DavidFoerster: this is the OP (essentially telling us to close the question)