# Can not install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xorg-video-abi-15 because of the error of unmet dependencies

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, xorg, nouveau

When trying to run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xorg-video-abi-15` I am having the following error, is there any solution for it.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

the output of `sudo apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libcheese-gtk23 is already the newest version.
libcheese-gtk23 set to manually installed.
libcheese7 is already the newest version.
libcheese7 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xorg-video-abi-15 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7`

```
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.0.10-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1:1.0.10-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://mirror.23media.de/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
xorg-video-abi-15:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libcheese-gtk23:
  Installed: 3.10.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.10.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://mirror.23media.de/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libcheese7:
  Installed: 3.10.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.10.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.10.2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://mirror.23media.de/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7`.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button below your question to add new information, especially command outputs. As you see, comments do not preserve any formatting and makes them hard to read. Please delete that comment and add the output to the question. Thanks! And while you're at it, also add the output of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xorg-video-abi-15 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7`.

Comment: I'm still missing the output of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xorg-video-abi-15 libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7`. Please add that as well.

Comment: @ByteCommander updated..

Comment: Okay, then please also the output of `apt-cache policy unity-control-center` - I overlooked that first, but if the new output wil tell me what I expect, you can simply solve the problem by running `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade`...

Answer (score -2):

Warning ! DO NOT DELETE AND REINSALL `libcheese-gtk23` or `libcheese7`,
If you do: it will work, but after reboot: X11 failed and you are good for reinstall ubuntu !

Try to install that (if it fail, don't force the installation)

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get -f install -y
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-utopic libglu1-mesa-dev
```

**EDIT: may be this one**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo ppa-purge  ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update
```

Source: [System settings stopped showing up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575548/system-settings-stopped-showing-up)

Comment: still getting the unmet dependencies error. :(

Comment: The first error output in the question actually says `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center` - so I don't think those libgl/mesa related packages will change a thing... I overlooked that at first too though.

Comment: @Uho Hed still no luck.

Comment: I'm sorry, i know these error are really frustrating. It depend of your system and what you have in it.  Warning again, if you delete or reinstall the wrong package (and if it is linked to X11), you will have trouble, i suggest you to make backup of your files before trying anything else